# Xamarin google play services login setup

Tags: xamarin.android, google-play-services

I am trying to hook a Xamarin project up to Google Play Services but keep receiving a `SIGN_IN_REQUIRED` error when calling `Connect`. I have read a few posts online but cannot determine what actually causes this error message.

I have setup the a game project and also setup an API with oAuth credentials. I have made sure that the same SHA key is being used in the API credentials and in the application while debugging but I am still not making any progress.

I am currently presuming that this is not a coding problem but rather something to do with the setup of the API services etc but have ran out of things to try at this point.

Comment: Firstly, to make sure your network connection is normal, you can run this demo in your network environment.https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/google-services/SigninQuickstart/  Donnot forget to change to `clientID` in string.xaml.Then , open the firebase console, find this app check the `clientID` if it is same with your code, and check the SHA-1 hash of your signing certificate.

Comment: Have this working now, not sure what was wrong but following these instructions from scratch seemed to resolve it. Thanks

Comment: I posted above solution as an answer, could you accept it and gets marked as answered? Helps other searching for questions to help on so they don't waste time on questions that are answered.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, to make sure your network connection is normal, you can run this demo in your network environment.developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/google-services/… Donnot forget to change to clientID in string.xaml.Then , open the firebase console, find this app check the clientID if it is same with your code, and check the SHA-1 hash of your signing certificate.